# Proper Setup for Internal and external network cards

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking

Currently I have the following setup

> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . :
> workhorse    
> Primary Dns Suffix  . . .
> . . . . : AVIAF.local   
>  Node Type . .
> . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid    
> IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No 
>    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
> DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . :
> AVIAF.local
>
> Ethernet adapter Internal Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> Description . . . . . . . . . . . :
> Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II GigE
> (NDIS  VBD Client)   
>  Physical
> Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-19-B9-E0-64-63   
>  DHCP Enabled. . .
> . . . . . . . . : No    
> IP Address. .
> . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.211
> Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . :
> 255.255.255.0   
>  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1  
>   DNS
> Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :
> 192.168.1.211   
>  Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.211
> Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . :
> 192.168.0.1
>
> Ethernet adapter External Connection:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> Description . . . . . . . . . . . :
> Broadcom BCM5708C NetXtreme II GigE
> (NDIS  VBD Client) #2   
>  Physical
> Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-19-B9-E0-64-65    
> DHCP Enabled. . .
> . . . . . . . . : No   
>  IP Address. .
> . . . . . . . . . . : 173.65.167.75
> Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . :
> 255.255.255.0   
>  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 173.65.167.1   
>  DNS
> Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :
> 68.238.0.12    
> Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.211   
>  Secondary
> WINS Server . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

I get error messages that pop up saying that dual gateways doesnt work for internal and external ... If I dont do that then one of the two network cards (the one without the gateway) stops responding to web calls

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" setup would *usually* be to have a default gateway on the external network interface and not having one on the internal one, but it can vary depending on your network configuration.

What do you mean by "stops responding to web calls"?
Web calls from where?
From the same network the card is connected to?
From another network reachable through that one?
From a proxy server?

Comment: Stops Responding to web calls means that I have IIS running websites that are both internal and external facing... if i turn off the gateway for lan internal then the local users cant access.  If I turn off the gateway for the external then the internet users can't access.   They are two network cards built in to the mother board of a dell 1950

Comment: Also no proxy servers anywhere... Its Fiber -> switch -> switch -> External Card     and Fiber -> switch -> router -> internal card

Comment: This is strange, the server should be able to properly talk to the network(s) it's directly connected to even without any defined gateway. Are you really saying that an internal computer with an address like 192.168.1.42 can't talk to your server if it doesn't have a default gateway on the internal interface?!?